# "Make A Buy" Vs "Make A Purchase"

Tags: meaning, usage, slang

Is the phrase "*make a buy*" is more casual version of "*make a purchase*"?

Comment: it sounds slang-y and informal.

Comment: This would be a lot more interesting with a specific explanation of what made you think of this: a quote that seems to show this, a summary of search results, or detailed reasoning based on their commonalities.

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=jYisFM7fLkEC&pg=PA157&dq=%22make+a+buy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifj7-b-YzKAhVI-GMKHWKuC7gQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20buy%22&f=false) shows that it is used in quite formal settings.

Answer (score 2):

**"Make a buy,"** to many Americans, means specifically that *illegal* drugs (or less commonly guns) were purchased.

---

The [Dictionary of Criminal Justice](https://books.google.com/books?id=U-NxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22make%20a%20buy%22%20%20drug&source=bl&ots=2tSOjqhuPU&sig=N3-OYo4RUscAtITYZIF8Q3irG0o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX7L_Z1q_LAhUC8GMKHaWJDkMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20buy%22%20%20drug&f=false) includes this term:

> **make a buy** To purchase drugs

---

And here is a usage in context from  [google](https://www.google.com/#q=%22make+a+buy%22++drug):

> "We don't want to just make a buy and make an arrest because then everyone knows who the informant is.

[Media Awareness Project](http://www.mapinc.org/drugnews/v02/n1623/a11.html?4950)

This link also includes *buy* used as an adjective, by the way: *Officers' **buy** money comes from their department's investigative funds.*

---

So it is not exactly synonymous.  If a friend told me he was going to run some errands and *make a purchase,* I would assume he is going to get a pair of pants, or a case of Ramen noodles.  If he said he is going to run some errands and *make a buy,* I would expect him to come back with cocaine or methamphetamines.

Answer (score 0):

*Buy* is a verb but not used very much as a noun.  When it is used as a noun, it typically refers to an event of buying and almost never an item that was bought.

*Purchase* can both be a verb and a noun with no problems - the noun will usually mean *item that was bought* but can also mean *the event of purchasing*.

Most of the time, if you want a single word to be the "noun" form of *buy* or *purchase*, use *purchase*.

Comment: "Our biggest sale of the year. Great *buys* all over the store!"

Comment: Good point, good point.

Comment: @meatie you have two answers to this question that address different levels of nuance.  Were either one of them helpful?

Answer (score -3):

No, because 'buy' is a verb and 'purchase' is a noun. By the way, why have you tagged this 'slang'? Do you know what 'slang' means? That's rhetorical, because evidently you do not, or you would not have tagged it as such. Please remove the 'slang' tag as it is not appropriate.

Comment: Verbing nouns may weird language, as Calvin & Hobbes famously had it, but the other way around also works at times, and often as slang.

Comment: If you want to comment about tags, do so in a comment, not in an answer. More importantly, [_purchase_ can function as both a noun **and** a verb](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/purchase).